Maximizing conditional Mutual Information
My goal is to find arg max of the mutual information of two variables given another variable:
$$
\max_{X}  \quad I(X;Y|Z) = I(X;Y) - I(X;Y;Z).
$$
Is it correct to rewrite the above as:
$$
\max_{X,X'} \quad I(X;Y) + \lambda I(X';Y;M)\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad  X \perp X' \;\;\; \text{or }\;\; I(X,X')=0
$$
In fact, can we optimize the $X$ with using $X'$ as auxiliary variable which is independent from $X$?
